# How to vertically center div in fluid container?

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to vertically center a div containing meta data such as Title and Author within a container that has a fluid width. In the example below, I would like the .meta div to be vertically centered within the article which is fluid width.

I tried following this article (http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) but it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <article>
        <div class="meta">
            <div class="title"></div>
            <div class="author"></div>
                    <img src="" />
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

**CSS (using LESS)**

```
.container {
    h3 {
        margin: -5px 0 0 0;
        padding: 32px 0px 16px 0;
        .freight-sans-pro;
        font-size: 1.375em;
        line-height: 1em;
        font-weight: 200;
    }
    article {
        max-height: 375px;
            overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 900;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        background-color: @color-black;
        line-height: 0em;
        a {
            max-height: 375px;
            display: block;
            img { opacity: .5; .opacity-transition; }
        }
        .meta {
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 40%;
            z-index: 500;
            padding: 0px 10%;
            color: @color-white;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            .title {
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 2em;
                line-height: 1em;
                font-weight: 700;
                text-shadow: 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                padding-bottom: 8px;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
            }
            .author {
                margin: 0;
                font-size: .8em;
                line-height: .75em;
                font-style: italic;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-shadow: 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)?

Comment: I have...no luck it just sticks to the top.

Comment: the article is using 'display:table', text-align:center, and 'vertival-align:middle', have you try it all?

Comment: Giving the LESS.css makes it quite a big harder to work with what you provided. Please http://jsfiddle.net a *working* example with output, not source, cotnent.

Comment: So you're trying to vertically center a **variable-height element**, is that correct? Not sure if the fluid width is relevant (other than to further suggest that the height of the content you're trying to center is very dynamic in nature).

Answer (score 0):

Tried your Less but got an error in codepen.io so could not debug.

You could try something simple like this:

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Check it working [here](http://codepen.io/domkoscielak/pen/DEisb)

You might find this article useful as well: http://logconsole.com/vertical-align-center-image/

It's about vertically centring image, but in most cases you could just change image with a div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on what you want to be centered.  I altered @domkoscielak's code so that it work.

```
.meta {
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -60px; /*half of height*/
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: You have a totally different approach here - with position absolute and negative margin. Check this codepen to see my code in action [http://codepen.io/domkoscielak/pen/DEisb](http://codepen.io/domkoscielak/pen/DEisb)

Comment: your method didn't work in the latest version of chrome  EDIT: I was thinking the middle of the page.  So nvm, it did work within the box.  However, I just don't like emulating tables in css.